# On Eclipse-Java EE, how do I change the color settings for selected elements on a tree view?

Tags: css, eclipse, color-scheme, eclipse-luna, eclipse-jee

I've recently switched to the dark theme on Eclipse Java EE Luna, even tried other dark themes such as moonrise, but I always end up having to tune some settings in order to be able to read things (which by the way I have to set up again every time I restart eclipse, I hope they fix that ticket soon!)

However, I couldn't figure out how to fix the most annoying problem. On some views, such as Navigator view I can read the selected item properly:
[image]

On others though (such as package explorer, search, and servers views), this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see the selected item text is quite difficult to read.

It's my understanding I cannot fix this by editing a config setting, but instead I have to open the CSS theme file and edit the property or properties. Only I don't know which one or which ones I have to edit. Any clues?

Comment: You can change the color of items in this view. Will it help your eyes?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I am about to give up and go back to the default white theme; I wanted to switch to dark because I noticed considerable less eye fatigue when I started working with PhpStorm's default theme, which is dark. On Eclipse-Java EE it only made things worse: The Java EE tools default color settings simply don't go along with any dark theme, and there is no settings menu to change many of those settings. I'd be happy if I could just edit whatever CSS properties are necessary to see all those views (package explorer, search results, servers) as I see the navigator view...

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: I am using windows. I read somewhere I could change the os theme to a dark one, but I've tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: (anyway I cannot change the OS theme anymore due to group policies establishing a corporate theme, so that wouldn't be an option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of items in the views. To do that navigate to `eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_x.x.x..../css` and open `e4-dark_win.css` file (if you are using windows). Find `CTabFolder Tree, CTabFolder Canvas` and `.MPartStack.active Tree, .MPartStack.active CTabFolder Canvas` definitions and change `color` to something more pleasing.

E.g.

```css
CTabFolder Tree, CTabFolder Canvas {
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
    color: #ffffaa;
}
.MPartStack.active Tree,
.MPartStack.active CTabFolder Canvas {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #ffffaa;
}
```

Comment: Good enough, although it would be better if I could change the highlighted/selected element background and/or font color instead (I keep looking for those CSS values but I don't find them. Maybe in the eclipse jee plugin folder?). Thank you!

Comment: How you figure out which style need to be modified? In my case, it's the projects and folders that Eclipse marks as modified (with that >), but the font is black. With dark theme, it's almost impossible to see.